# Is it possible to make Hibernate DML statements to include return/output clause

Tags: hibernate, dml

Both SQLServer and Oracle have ability to return new values into client application (`OUTPUT` and `RETURN` clause respectively) after executing DML statements. Is it possible somehow to use these values with Hibernate, so I don't have to issue `refresh` ?
I know this feature is server-dependent and won't work if RDMS doesn't support it.